# Putting all results of a query in a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'd like to know how to make a predicate that puts all results obtained from some query (so I get a result and press semicolon until I get False) in a list.

For example if I write `foo(X,[1,2,3]).` in some Prolog listener, let's say the result is

```
X=[11];
X=[22];
False.
```

I would like to get all those results in a list, so something like the following would happen.

```
?-another_foo(X,[1,2,3]).
X=[[11],[22]].
```

another_foo would somehow use foo to create a list with all the results from foo.
I just don't know how.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the built-in predicate `findall/3`:

```
?-findall(X0, foo(X0, [1,2,3]), X).
X = [[11], [22]].
```

You can define your `another_foo/2`:

```
another_foo(X, Input) :-
  findall(X0, foo(X0, Input), X).
```