# Prolog, how to collect all possible result in one list

Tags: recursion, prolog

```
powerset([a,b,c ],X)
```

```
X = [a, b, c]
X = [a, c, b]
X = [b, a, c]
X = [b, c, a]
X = [c, a, b]
X = [c, b, a]
X = [a, b]
X = [b, a]
X = [a, c]
X = [c, a]
X = [a]
X = [b, c]
X = [c, b]
X = [b]
X = [c]
X = []
```

Those are all possible result . But now, I want to make those results into one list. How can I get it in prolog?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you save all possible solutions in SWI-Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638034/how-do-you-save-all-possible-solutions-in-swi-prolog)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Putting all results of a query in a list in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340022/putting-all-results-of-a-query-in-a-list-in-prolog)

Answer (score -1):

Use findall built-in function. I got it.

Comment: I am giving this a downvote because it is a duplicate question. The question and answer should both be deleted.